# How to generate a default name for a DB entity that is not duplicate?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a requirement to generate a unique name for a new instance of a database entity.

Now, one option that readily seems like a good solution is giving a name like 'Unnamed EntityX - ID' where ID is the ID of the instance. Problem with this approach is we don't know the ID upfront.

Another option is to save twice - once with an invalid name like 'Unnamed EntityX - RANDOM_NUMBER;%;' and then save again with name 'Unnamed EntityX - ID'.
There are two issues with this approach:

1. It seems incorrect to save twice.
2. It seems incorrect to save with incorrect name even if temporary.

A third option is to save with 'Unnamed EntityX - RANDOM_NUMBER' and if that is duplicate, then try the second option above.

What's the best practice (or common practice) in this case? I feel like the second approach is the best option.

Details: I am using grails 2.4.4 with native ID generation.

Comment: Why do you have to save the number part at all? Just concatenate name with the id in a utility getter in the entity.

Comment: What is the significant of having unique name. In your case ID should serve your requirement, which is unique already.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Each entity instance has to have unique name for user to see! For a new entity instance, ID is unavailable but it still has to be saved to DB with unique name.

Comment: for that purpose you can just create a transient variable 'name' and override its getter to return "Unnamed EntityX - ID".

Answer (score -1):

easiest way is to generate a unique identifier and use it.

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```